# Is Salesforce Affected by the RunC Vulnerability in Docker?

Tags: dockercloud

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/runc-vulnerability-gives-attackers-root-access-on-docker-kubernetes-hosts/

"A container breakout security flaw found in the runc container runtime allows malicious containers (with minimal user interaction) to overwrite the host runc binary and gain root-level code execution on the host machine."

Comment: Why would Docker have anything to do with Salesforce?

Comment: I am not sure if Salesforce is using docker in its architecture.  I saw these two links:  https://www.salesforce.com/video/192749/

https://techcrunch.com/2018/11/15/docker-inks-partnership-with-mulesoft-as-salesforce-takes-a-strategic-stake/

Comment: [Understanding the Salesforce Architecture](https://www.salesforce.com/video/306503/) is probably a better resource to be looking at rather than a video talking about docker and Heroku. At any rate though, I don't really think any non-Salesforce employee is going to be able to answer this one beyond "Salesforce is a managed service, if it's a problem, it's their problem, and they will take appropriate steps. There is nothing you, personally, can do."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce runs on Sun Application servers, not Docker. It's primarily a blend of Java and Oracle underneath. As such, Salesforce itself is safe from this exploit. Heroku, now a salesforce.com product, may have been affected, but most likely has been updated with the patch by now (but I can't find a resource to prove this).

Comment: It has been publicly stated that salesforce runs jetty as of 2014 for the servlet container (this is of course subject to change without notice) https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/07/open-source-at-salesforce-com.html

Comment: @ca_peterson Deep down inside, I knew that. I've seen Jetty proxy errors before. Cool bit of information to have confirmed, though.